# How can I download the large file from google drive using rclone?

Tags: download, google-drive-shared-drive, rclone

Now I want to download the dataset on the website(http://pubchemqc.riken.jp/), it's in google drive and filesize is 2TB. the website recommend using rclone to download the file but not said how to use.
[As the picture shows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57dvl.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This was asked a while back already but I'd like to keep it recorded here as it seems hard to find.
Unfortunately I don't know if there's a way to automate this process but it's still easy.

What you can do is create a new remote with the link's `root_folder_id`.
The Root Folder ID is present in the `url` e.g:
in the example link
`https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/a1b2c3deFgHi4JKlm56nOpqrStuv7w8xy9`

the `root_folder_id` is the string after the slash `/folders/` so in this case it would be "`a1b2c3deFgHi4JKlm56nOpqrStuv7w8xy9`". If the Google Drive shared link you got is a folder all you have to do is copy that `id` and use it in the rclone's new remote setup. Now if the shared link points directly to a file, like the one in the OP, there's no folder to download it from, so we gotta create our own! The whole process would look like:

- get the `folder_id` from Google Drive's link. If it is a link to a direct file then first we have to create a new folder anywhere inside our own Google Drive, it's name doesn't matter as we will point directly to it using the ID. After creating this new folder, open it and note the url, it should look something like
  `https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/Fdrcv3nQvxQqXUGEEyvacwUxdYXpV33Ct`

just copy everything *after* `/folders/` and save it for later.

- now go back to the link of the direct file. Add a shortcut for that file *to* inside your recently created folder, so say the folder was named `dl-with-rclone`, click the "Add shortcut to Drive" icon and navigate to the "`dl-with-rclone`" folder to add the shortcut there.

##### heading to `rclone`, do:

- `rclone config` *<to open settings>*
- On the prompt `e/n/d/r/c/s/q>` hit `n` *(the key relative to creating a new remote)*
- On `name>` give it a name like `sharedWithMe` or anything else for personal reference later
- On the prompt `Storage>`, the possible remotes to connect to, write down `drive` or the number relative to it (currently `15`)
- if you set up your own `client_id` and `client_secret` you put them next
- On the `scope>` prompt option `2` "Read-only" is enough

*now this is the important one:*

- on the `root_folder_id>` prompt input the ID of the folder of the shared link or the folder you created and pointed the file shortcut to, e.g. `Fdrcv3nQvxQqXUGEEyvacwUxdYXpV33Ct`

Now you can pretty much hit enter for everything, once you reach `Use auto config?` you will be redirected for a browser to login. Make sure the logged in account is the same that you created the folder for the shortcut. If the shared link is for a folder already your logged in account doesn't matter.

After finishing your remote setup you can exit `rclone config`

The command you would need would be something like `rclone copy sharedWithMe: destination/folder`

This being rclone you would surely be able to copy from one remote to another, that's up to the user.

In summary: I did test this method on your link, creating a folder in my Drive, pointing the file shortcut to it and using the `root_folder_id` to setup the rclone remote and it did begin to download:

[rclone test download screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbaVV.png)

Comment: Thank you for this detailed answer. I definitely learnt a lot.

Comment: Is there any way to automate this? This is awfully painful, I'd like to provide my clients with an option to send files to our systems directly from google drive. It seems - the easiest things to do would be: "paste a public link to your file", but it seems to be so troublesome...

Comment: Works great, but I had to go to advanced configuration to get the root_folder_id prompt. Seems like it isn't part of the standard configuration anymore.